# A way to avoid JSP and HTML tag syntax blurring (<, / and > chars)?

Tags: java, jsp, coding-style, template-engine

I read http://www.smarty.net/syntax_comparison and main point that instead of `<`, `/`, `>` symbols used `{` and `}`. Same situation in Python Django template syntax engine.

But when come to Java JSP you get such hard readable code:

```
<div <c:if test="${bean != null}">style="text-align:center"</c:if>>${bean.title}</div>
```

or:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/show/${group.id}.htm"/>">${group.name}</a>
```

This sequences: `"</c:if>>$`, `"/>">${`, `="<c:url value="/` from above code look *very* cryptic to me.

There are a bunch of problems:

- Using JSP `"` in HTML `"`.
- Using JSP `<>`, `</>` in HTML `<>`, `</>`.

EL simplify looking of JSP but not so match. Also reformatting code make it a little bit readable. But *why* JSP syntax so *dumb*? And is it possible to workaround JSP syntax blurring with HTML/XML syntax in some way?

Comment: Cleaner syntax can be achieved by using alternate expressions (e.g. `${bean == null ? '' : 'style="text-align:center"'}`) and by using (custom) functions.

Answer (score 5):

That is just the syntax of JSP, there is no point getting annoyed by it. Obviously you should format your code nicer in order to make it as easy as possible to read.

If you dont like it you can try Freemarker or Velocity as alternative templating languages:

http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/

http://velocity.apache.org/

I personally find freemarker the easiest to read.

One other alternative suggested by artbristol is thymeleaf:

http://www.thymeleaf.org/

Comment: Interesting, but I stuck to JSP in current project and JSP is **standard** from big companies... +1

Comment: JSP isnt standard, Ive worked with big companies who work with both of the above suggestions. However, I appreciate that it might be a project standard that you cant change

Comment: @artbristol thanks for pointing to **thymeleaf**. First look give me that looping in themeleaf is some hard (with `th:each`)... +1

Comment: As the author I would recommend you to try Rythm(http://rythmengine.com/) template engine. It has an nice Razor like syntax. The engine is put into real project usage for one year. Someone has created a Spring plugin for it: https://github.com/lawrence0819/spring-web-rythm-template. Also you might want to check out this template engine benchmark program: https://github.com/greenlaw110/template-engine-benchmarks. Just download the zip file and run `ant help`